# What does "shotgun parser" mean?

Tags: security

Heard this term in talk [The Science of Insecurity](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3kEfedtQVOY) but I am not sure what does it mean.

Comment: See also the blog post [Parse, don't validate](https://lexi-lambda.github.io/blog/2019/11/05/parse-don-t-validate/) by Alexis King, which (while not exactly about this in particular) mentions this in passing.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Shotgun parsing is an antipattern in the processing of input, [defined](http://langsec.org/papers/langsec-cwes-secdev2016.pdf) as

> Shotgun parsing is a programming antipattern whereby parsing and input-validating code is **mixed with**  and  **spread  across**  processing  code—throwing  a  cloud of  checks  at  the  input,  and  hoping,  without  any  systematic justification,  that  one  or  another  would  catch  all  the  “bad” cases.

Properly handling input is a key aspect of secure programming, and "shotgun parsers" make programs more prone to exploitable security weaknesses. Unfortunately, like several other inherently insecure techniques, it's a popular approach to input parsing.